# Exception EPackageError in module rtl70.bpl. Cannot load package 'delphide70'

Tags: delphi-7

Sometime yesterday, an error started appearing each time that I open Delphi (7). The error is:

> Exception EPackageError in module rtl70.bpl at 0001874D.
>
> Cannot load package 'delphide70.' It contains unit 'PasCompilerMessageOptionsPage' which is also contained in package 'delphide70'.
>
> Do you want to attempt you load this IDE package the next time that Delphi is run?

I was not doing anything related to installing packages, Delphi, or any such thing.

I have used Delphi for many years, and this is the first time that I have seen this error.

Subsequently, I tried re-installing the latest update (that I have) `d7_pro_upd1_1.exe` and that did not seem to make any difference.

I also considered that perhaps there was a duplicate copy of `delphide` that was causing problems, but I cannot find any evidence of that.

I assume that something got corrupted somewhere and needs to be re-installed.

I am reluctant to completely re-install Delphi for fear that I might have to re-install all of the packages that have been added.

Any thought, suggestions or hints would be welcomed.